# Strange GET requests to my site

Tags: django, url, google-analytics, get

In the last days, Google Analytics is showing me some strange GET methods that have been requested on my website.

I have no clue if it is done by robots or humans or if it is some kind of attack or something harmless. They are coming from different countries, which for me is even more confusing because it seems like they are not only one person/robot.

Some examples of these urls are:

```
 - /en/?lipi=urn:li:page:d_flagship3_feed;ipLRICUhTrGXGdPXnW0tnQ==

 - /en/?lipi=urn:li:page:d_flagship3_feed;3kcVPzepRVGxY7MZjonjig==

 - /en/?lipi=urn:li:page:d_flagship3_feed;mFWFR+VMS0SHqJTkYN87EA==

 - /en/?_sm_pdc=1&_sm_rid=7MV6JrjR5MSrPHJMDDrtjMMQZVz6lqJrH02kZVk
```

Does anybody have an idea what that is?

Comment: They seem to be to do with farming. Maybe your domain name is similar to something relevant?

Comment: It is indeed similar to other domains of websites that are bigger, but not really huge websites. What is farming in this context?

Comment: sometimes people write selenium/beautiful soup scripts to randomly check sites for security issues, secret information or whatever they are interested in. They check all kinds of urls or maybe do an SQL injection. With a proper setup you dont have to worry. You could also write a script which detects suspicious users and kicks them out.

Comment: No idea, sorry. I just googled some of the terms.

Comment: I see... Thanks to both. If any of you want to create an answer with the comments and some reference to how to kick them out, I will gladly mark it as accepted.

Comment: @J0ANMM Are you running any linkedIn inmail ad campaigns or any other ad campaigns?

Comment: @SathishkumarJayaraj No, no compaigns.

Comment: I am seeing this too.  I first noticed it showing up as a landing page in google analytics.  after googling, I see similar strings appended to a wide array of urls.  it's always "/?lipi=urn:li:page:d_flagship3_company;" with some gobbledygook at the end.  makes sense that it is some sort of probe for security issues.  would be nice to know what, exactly, is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "_sm_pdc" and "_sm_rid" are added by the ZScalar Proxy (https://www.zscaler.com/) when it confirms with the user that they really wanted to visit your site.